# Sum of pairs from list: memoization, design optimalization

Tags: python, design-patterns, memoization

From a list of integers and a single sum value, I have to return the first two values in order of appearance that adds up to the sum. [source of the task](https://www.codewars.com/kata/54d81488b981293527000c8f/train/python)

I think the most optimal way to scan the list is:

1. ```
   index 0, index 1
   ```
2. ```
   index 0,          index 2
   ```
3. ```
            index 1, index 2
   ```
4. ```
   index 0,                   index 3
   ```
5. ```
           index 1,           index 3
   ```
6. ```
                     index 2, index 3
   ```

and so on. Am I right so far?

Then I used memoization to cut numbers appearing more than twice.

The code I wrote is functional but times-out on the more advanced tests. Here it is:

```
def sum_pairs(ints, s):
d={}
n2_index = 0
d[ints[0]] = 1
while True:
    n2_index += 1
    if ints[n2_index] not in d.keys():
        d[ints[n2_index]] = 0
        
    if d[ints[n2_index]] == 2:
        if n2_index == len(ints)-1:
            return None
        continue
    for n1_index in range (0, n2_index):

        if ints[n1_index] + ints[n2_index] == s:
            return [ints[n1_index], ints[n2_index]]
    
    d[ints[n2_index]] += 1
    
    if n2_index == len(ints)-1:
        return None
```

I would appreciate it greatly if you could help me understand my mistake/mistakes and how to approach this kind of task.
Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this is to remember all the numbers you have seen before.  This is normaly done in a set, a set is gives you O(1) (constant) look up time, so you determine very fast if you have seen a particular number or not already.

As you can through the list, you look in your set to see if you have seen the `sum - current_value`.  If so you can output these two values, if not you add the current_value to the set and continue.

```
def sum(ints, s):
    seen = set()
    for current_value in ints:
        if s - current_value in seen:
             return s-current_value, current_value
        else:
             seen.add(current_value)
    return None
```